# Position fixed of buttons to bottom and inside of scrollable menu Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css

I try to position:fixed two buttons to the bottom of a fixed-height scrollable menu in Bootstrap 3.
With position:fixed, the scrollability is lost and the buttons falls outside the menu. Is it possible to fix it neatly inside in a scrollable menu and so it is always visible but not part of the "side-scroll" (= see concept image)?

This is my concept: Where it says "Übernehmen"; there I want my APPLY + CLEAR buttons.

[image: Concept]

```css
.scrollable-menu {
    height: auto;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.checkbox :hover {
      background-color:red;
      cursor:pointer;
     width:100%;
    }

.div_form :hover {
      background-color:green;
      cursor:pointer;
    }

.btn_clear {
    float: right;
display: inline-block;
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 50%;
padding: 10px 17px;
text-align: center;
  }
  
.btn_apply {
      float: left;
display: inline-block;
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 50%;
padding: 10px 17px;
text-align: center;
    }

.div_form {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-toolbar">
        <!--Default buttons with dropdown menu-->
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Brand</button>
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button"><span class="caret"></span></button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" style="margin-left: 2em">
                <input class="typeahead" placeholder="Search values" type="text">
    <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input value="" type="checkbox"> Alpha</label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input value="" type="checkbox"> Beta
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input value="" type="checkbox"> Gamma</label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input value="" type="checkbox"> Delta</label>
                </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input value="" type="checkbox"> Omega</label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input value="" type="checkbox"> Koppa
                    </label>
                </div>
    <div class="div_form">
       <span class="btn_apply" id="apply">Apply</span>
                  <span class="btn_clear"><input class="clear" type="checkbox">Clear</span>
     </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--Primary buttons with dropdown menu-->
        </div>
        <!--Success buttons with dropdown menu-->
```

Comment: please see to my answer. Is't ok. If not let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added some extra element and have given it `position: relative;` and its child `position:absolute;` then to parent `margin-bottom:70px;` and its child `bottom:-70px;`
have a look on this: https://jsfiddle.net/2v7wq5k0/3/

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I was after. Thanks a lot!